# Google+ share button with preview text + image

Tags: google-plus, schema.org, microdata

I try to add a Google+ button to my page. The button itself works, but the text and the image are always empty. I annotated my body and some elements with the schema.org tags, but it is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article"> 
    <div itemprop="name">This is the article name</div>
    <img itemprop="image" src="thumbnail.jpg" />
    <p itemprop="description">This is the description of the article.</p>

     <g:plus action="share" href="testUrl"></g:plus>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.___gcfg = {
        lang: 'en-US'
      };

      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>

</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can debug what microdata is getting parsed by using the [Google Structured Data Testing Tool.](http://google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) This can help you to understand what Google is seeing on your microdata annotations.

Try removing the URL from your share / +1. The target Url will fallback to the current page, which I'm assuming is you want people to share.

If that's not the problem, there are a few other things that might help:

**Your snippet:**

Did you use the [Google+ Snippet generator](http://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet)? It tends to work pretty well. Also, if you have a complex page, it can help to use meta tags in the `<header>` section to begin with for debugging.

**Proxies:**
Which brings me to the next point, if there is a proxy blocking your page or security that prevents people from accessing it, that will block the share preview renderer. Make sure your page (share target) is publicly accessible.

Another possibility: if your page is cached in your server's proxy, this will prevent the page from being updated by the share preview renderer.

If you add an anchor link or query string to the end of the url, e.g. foo.com/index.html vs foo.com/index.html#test vs foo.com/index.html?test=yes it should ensure that a cached version without microdata will be included.

Comment: I tried to remove the url, I used the snipped, tried to add the tags to header, but without success.

Comment: Try the structured data testing tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets to see what data Google sees when parsing your annotations. You might be encountering the proxy issue, if you add an anchor link or query string to the end of the url, e.g. http://foo.com/index.html vs http://foo.com/index.html#test vs http://foo.com/index.html?test=yes it should ensure that a cached version without microdata will be included. Also, if you can share a link to the troublesome page, it could be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the href attribute on your g:plus tag. Instead, change it to data-href.